# Erro em serialize jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var Dados = {};

Dados.email = jQuery("#email").val();
Dados.nome= jQuery("#nome").val();

var urlparams = Dados.serialize();
```

Meu console retorna **Dados.serialize is not a function** tem algum erro no código?

Comment: Isso porque `Dados` não é um objeto jQuery. E se fizer `jQuery(Dados).serialize()`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss desculpe, não entendi sua pergunta

Comment: Os parametros vem em branco

Comment: var Dados = {};
    Dados.email = "email";
    Dados.nome = "nome";

    var urlparams = jQuery(Dados).serialize();

 alert(urlparams);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está usando o método errado. O método [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), de acordo com a documentação, é usado para criar uma string no padrão *URL-encoded* através de um objeto jQuery que tenha selecionado campos de formulários, como `input`s, `select`s e `textarea`s, ou o próprio formulário.

O que você procura é a função **[`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)**, que cria uma representação serializada dos dados de um objeto:

```js
const string = $.param({
  name: 'Luiz Felipe',
  nickname: 'lffg'
});

console.log(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Referência:

- [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/);
- [`.serialize()` (jQuery)](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: +1 Boa resposta! Eu só acrescentaria que o `serialize` deve ser usado, ou em um `form`, ou em uma seleção apenas de `input`, `textarea` e `select` , como mostra na documentação que você mencionou:  `$( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();`

Comment: Obrigado! Irei editar a resposta em breve. No entanto, me ative mais à função `$.param()`, já que ela é o foco da pergunta, e não `.serialize()`.  :)

Comment: Entendo, só achei válido nesse caso pois é citada a documentação do `serialize` e ficaria mais completo para quem ler. Mesmo que a função `$.param` seja o foco. :D

Comment: Editei. Valeu! ;)